# How can I get the contents of a file one line at a time?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a project where a user uploads a photo with a name and caption, and I am having trouble with displaying the name and caption.

Right now, it's displaying the entire text file with each image, and I am having trouble fixing this.

My code so far:

```
    <?php
        $Dir = "files";
        $DirEntries = scandir($Dir);
        foreach ($DirEntries as $Entry)
        {
            if((strcmp($Entry, '.') != 0) && (strcmp($Entry, '..') != 0))
            {
                echo "<p>Name: " . file_get_contents("imagelist.txt") . "</p>";
                echo "<a href=\"files/" . $Entry . "\" target=\"_blank\" >" . $Entry . "</a><br />\n";  
            }
        }
        closedir($DirOpen);         
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use file_get_contents(), which does read the entire file into one giant string..... either use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) which returns an array, with each line as an individual array entry, or open the file manually with [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and iterate over it using [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read it one line at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fgets()`:

```
$inputFile = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($inputFile) {
    while (($line = fgets($inputFile)) !== false) {
        echo $line."<br>";
        // The process read the file line by line        
    }
} else {
    echo "There was an error in the opening file";
} 
fclose($inputFile);
```